# Character encoding cross-reference

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, ascii, iso-8859-1, cross-reference

I have just migrated a database containing Latin American place names from MS Access to my MySQL. In the process, every instance of **á** has been changed to **‡**. Here is my question:

Does there exist some sort of reference for looking up which character encoding has been translated to which other? For example, a place where I can enter a character and see how it would be misrepresented after a variety of erroneous encoding translations (e.g. ASCII to ISO 8859-1, ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8, etc.)?

Comment: Probably not. You should probably just look for a way to fix the data in the MySQL database. If you just want to see the mistranslation in action, use a text viewer that lets you choose the encoding to use for reading the file, right?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of, but if you have a list of possible encodings, you can write a simple program like:

```
for x in ENCODINGS:
    for y in ENCODINGS:
        try:
            if 'á'.encode(x) == '‡'.encode(y):
                print(x, '→', y)
        except UnicodeError:
            pass
```

Doing that, it appears in your case that the original encoding is one of:

- mac_arabic
- mac_centeuro
- mac_croatian
- mac_farsi
- mac_iceland
- mac_latin2
- mac_roman
- mac_romanian
- mac_turkish

and the misinterpreted encoding is one of:

- cp1250
- cp1251
- cp1252
- cp1253
- cp1254
- cp1255
- cp1256
- cp1257
- cp1258
- palmos

If you live in a "Western" locale, then mac_roman → cp1252 is the most likely possibility.